# Core Data to create contacts?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Creating a user heavy application and am a bit lost on what to do as far as the editing and saving data to a user goes. Can anyone push me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: What is a "user heavy application"?

Comment: like an address book with contacts and information for each individual contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the beautiful things about CoreData is that, once you create your data model, you are largely relieved from the details of how to write, edit and save the data itself.  Of course, if you want to you can take control of those details.

I'd suggest you look at the tutorials here:  http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_6_iPhone_Core_Data_Tutorial

That will definitely set you on the right course.  I think you'll find it's actually very easy!